# How to reverse the order of legend Items when using dygraphs?

Tags: javascript, css, dygraphs

I have a series of 5 area plots to be drawn in a single figure. I am using dygraphs for this.

I want the legend to be displayed in reverse order, but I don't want to change my .csv file. I didn't find anything to solve this issue in the dygraphs documentation page.

Kindly help me with the way out.

The code looks like this:

```html
 <script type="text/javascript"  src="dygraph.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" src="dygraph.css" />
 <div id="graphdiv3"  style="width:1000px; height:300px;"></div>
 <div id="status", class="status"></div>
 <script>
  var g3 = new Dygraph(
     document.getElementById("graphdiv3"),
     "data/area.csv",
      {labelsDiv: document.getElementById('status'),
      labelsSeparateLines: true,
      labelsKMB: true,
      legend: 'always',
      xlabel: 'Date',
      ylabel: 'Area',
      drawGrid: false,
      rollPeriod: 10,
      showRoller: true,
      fillGraph: true,
      fillAlpha: 1.0,
      showRangeSelector: true,
      interactionModel: Dygraph.defaultInteractionModel,
   }
)
```

Comment: Read the file/lines in reverse?

Comment: Reading the file in reverse order will change the order of plotting (I guess). I don't want that.

Comment: Capture the legend details while plotting and then reverse it before you apply it. Also, you need to provide a code sample if you want anyone to assist you.

Comment: I am a beginner. I don't understand the technical things about how to do that. Is there any example of this method?

Comment: Post sample CSV data.

Comment: The data is available in this link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-2VD5eAljHpv8WIPL0z6nlT0weisHtAE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you not reverse the columns (after the first column) in the CSV? You want the legend to be displayed as `class6` to `class1` ?

Comment: No, I can not reverse the column. In my data, the last column has highest values. If I bring that in the first column, that hides other plots with lower values. As I want the area to be filled I can not change the order. But I want the legend in reverse order because that makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use `flex` and reverse `flex-direction`:

```js
var csv = btoa(`Year-month,class1,class2,class3,class5,class6
1982-01-01,0.617100372,2.669144981,6.43866171,17.15241636,30.49070632
1982-02-01,0.081784387,1.278810409,3.955390335,12.29739777,24.58736059
1982-03-01,0.104089219,0.996282528,3.568773234,11.98513011,21.81412639
1982-04-01,0.022304833,0.505576208,2.453531599,9.56133829,19.97769517
1982-05-01,0.215613383,2.066914498,7.152416357,18.47583643,31.21189591
1982-06-01,0.133828996,1.144981413,4.29739777,15.53159851,29.40520446
1982-07-01,3.910780669,8.505576208,16.69144981,35.10037175,48.4535316
1982-08-01,0.609665428,3.353159851,8.698884758,21.0260223,31.81412639
1982-09-01,2.579925651,6.059479554,12.95910781,29.91821561,43.04089219
1982-10-01,4.661710037,10.73605948,20.92193309,39.18215613,52.46096654
1982-11-01,0.713754647,2.750929368,7.420074349,17.23420074,27.67286245
1982-12-01,0.795539033,2.788104089,7.31598513,18.04460967,29.76951673`);

var g3 = new Dygraph(
  document.getElementById("graphdiv3"),
  'data:application/text+csv;base64,' + csv, {
    labelsDiv: document.getElementById('status'),
    labelsSeparateLines: true,
    labelsKMB: true,
    legend: 'always',
    xlabel: 'Date',
    ylabel: 'Area',
    drawGrid: false,
    rollPeriod: 10,
    showRoller: true,
    fillGraph: true,
    fillAlpha: 1.0,
    showRangeSelector: true,
    interactionModel: Dygraph.defaultInteractionModel,
  }
)
```

```css
#status {display:flex; flex-direction:column-reverse}
#status span {order:-1}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dygraph/2.1.0/dygraph.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dygraph/2.1.0/dygraph.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="graphdiv3" style="width:1000px; height:300px;"></div>
<div id="status" class="status"></div>
```

Comment: There is a `legendFormatter` option for the graph. I implemented an alternative solution below.

Answer (score 1):

The [`legendFormatter`](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#legendFormatter) option lets you customize legend formatting to your heart's content. In this case, you can call the default formatter and then reverse the lines. You'll need to take care to keep the x-axis label on the top when it's visible (assuming that's the desired behavior):

```js
function legendFormatter(data, ...args) {
  const html = Dygraph.Plugins.Legend.defaultFormatter(data, ...args);
  let lines = html.split(/<br\/?>/);
  if (data.x == null) {
    lines.reverse();
  } else {
    lines = [lines[0], ...lines.slice(1).reverse()];
  }
  return lines.join('<br>');
}

var csv = btoa(`Year-month,class1,class2,class3,class5,class6
1982-01-01,0.617100372,2.669144981,6.43866171,17.15241636,30.49070632
1982-02-01,0.081784387,1.278810409,3.955390335,12.29739777,24.58736059
1982-03-01,0.104089219,0.996282528,3.568773234,11.98513011,21.81412639
1982-04-01,0.022304833,0.505576208,2.453531599,9.56133829,19.97769517
1982-05-01,0.215613383,2.066914498,7.152416357,18.47583643,31.21189591
1982-06-01,0.133828996,1.144981413,4.29739777,15.53159851,29.40520446
1982-07-01,3.910780669,8.505576208,16.69144981,35.10037175,48.4535316
1982-08-01,0.609665428,3.353159851,8.698884758,21.0260223,31.81412639
1982-09-01,2.579925651,6.059479554,12.95910781,29.91821561,43.04089219
1982-10-01,4.661710037,10.73605948,20.92193309,39.18215613,52.46096654
1982-11-01,0.713754647,2.750929368,7.420074349,17.23420074,27.67286245
1982-12-01,0.795539033,2.788104089,7.31598513,18.04460967,29.76951673`);

var g3 = new Dygraph(
  document.getElementById("graphdiv3"),
  'data:application/text+csv;base64,' + csv, {
    labelsDiv: document.getElementById('status'),
    labelsSeparateLines: true,
    labelsKMB: true,
    legend: 'always',
    xlabel: 'Date',
    ylabel: 'Area',
    drawGrid: false,
    rollPeriod: 10,
    showRoller: true,
    fillGraph: true,
    fillAlpha: 1.0,
    showRangeSelector: true,
    interactionModel: Dygraph.defaultInteractionModel,
    legendFormatter: legendFormatter
  }
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dygraph/2.1.0/dygraph.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dygraph/2.1.0/dygraph.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="graphdiv3" style="width:1000px; height:300px;"></div>
<div id="status" class="status"></div>
```

For a more complex transformation, you'll be better off building up the HTML constructively. View source on the [legendFormatter demo](http://dygraphs.com/tests/legend-formatter.html) for an example.

Comment: I was reading through the source code and noticed this option. I actually skipped reading the API. You can check out my full example below.

Comment: Also, this fancy HTML splitting trick will not work when `labelsSeparateLines` is `false`.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide you own custom legend renderer, but Kosh's CSS alteration is much simpler.

Anyways, if you take a look at the Dygraph source code, you will notice that at the very end of the static `Legend.generateLegendHTML` function, there is a check for this option: `g.getOption('legendFormatter')`.

This means that you can provide your own version of `Legend.defaultFormatter`.

All I did was change the two places where `data.series` are referenced and called `data.series.reverse()` instead. Also, I jazzed it up a bit and made it more ES6 friendly.

```js
{
  legendFormatter: reverseLegendFormatter
}
```

```js
const csv = btoa(`Year-month,class1,class2,class3,class5,class6
1982-01-01,0.617100372,2.669144981,6.43866171,17.15241636,30.49070632
1982-02-01,0.081784387,1.278810409,3.955390335,12.29739777,24.58736059
1982-03-01,0.104089219,0.996282528,3.568773234,11.98513011,21.81412639
1982-04-01,0.022304833,0.505576208,2.453531599,9.56133829,19.97769517
1982-05-01,0.215613383,2.066914498,7.152416357,18.47583643,31.21189591
1982-06-01,0.133828996,1.144981413,4.29739777,15.53159851,29.40520446
1982-07-01,3.910780669,8.505576208,16.69144981,35.10037175,48.4535316
1982-08-01,0.609665428,3.353159851,8.698884758,21.0260223,31.81412639
1982-09-01,2.579925651,6.059479554,12.95910781,29.91821561,43.04089219
1982-10-01,4.661710037,10.73605948,20.92193309,39.18215613,52.46096654
1982-11-01,0.713754647,2.750929368,7.420074349,17.23420074,27.67286245
1982-12-01,0.795539033,2.788104089,7.31598513,18.04460967,29.76951673`);

const g3 = new Dygraph(
  document.getElementById("graphdiv3"),
  'data:application/text+csv;base64,' + csv, {
    labelsDiv: document.getElementById('status'),
    labelsSeparateLines: true,
    labelsKMB: true,
    legend: 'always',
    xlabel: 'Date',
    ylabel: 'Area',
    drawGrid: false,
    rollPeriod: 10,
    showRoller: true,
    fillGraph: true,
    fillAlpha: 1.0,
    showRangeSelector: true,
    interactionModel: Dygraph.defaultInteractionModel,
    legendFormatter: reverseLegendFormatter
  }
)

function reverseLegendFormatter(data) {
  let g = data.dygraph;
  if (g.getOption('showLabelsOnHighlight') !== true) return '';
  let sepLines = g.getOption('labelsSeparateLines'), htmlLines = [];
  if (typeof data.x === 'undefined') {
    if (g.getOption('legend') != 'always') return '';
    data.series.reverse()
      .filter(series => series.isVisible)
      .forEach(series => {
        htmlLines.push(`
          <span style="font-weight:bold; color:${series.color}">
            ${series.dashHTML} ${series.labelHTML}
          </span>
        `);
      });
  } else {
    htmlLines.push(`${data.xHTML}:`);
    data.series.reverse()
      .filter(series => series.isVisible)
      .forEach(series => {
        htmlLines.push(`
          <span${ series.isHighlighted ? ' class="highlight"' : '' }>
            <b><span style="color: ${series.color}">${series.labelHTML}</span></b>:
            &#160;${series.yHTML}
          </span>
        `);
      });
  }
  return htmlLines.join(sepLines ? '<br />' : '');
}
```

---

### Demo

```js
const csv = btoa(`Year-month,class1,class2,class3,class5,class6
1982-01-01,0.617100372,2.669144981,6.43866171,17.15241636,30.49070632
1982-02-01,0.081784387,1.278810409,3.955390335,12.29739777,24.58736059
1982-03-01,0.104089219,0.996282528,3.568773234,11.98513011,21.81412639
1982-04-01,0.022304833,0.505576208,2.453531599,9.56133829,19.97769517
1982-05-01,0.215613383,2.066914498,7.152416357,18.47583643,31.21189591
1982-06-01,0.133828996,1.144981413,4.29739777,15.53159851,29.40520446
1982-07-01,3.910780669,8.505576208,16.69144981,35.10037175,48.4535316
1982-08-01,0.609665428,3.353159851,8.698884758,21.0260223,31.81412639
1982-09-01,2.579925651,6.059479554,12.95910781,29.91821561,43.04089219
1982-10-01,4.661710037,10.73605948,20.92193309,39.18215613,52.46096654
1982-11-01,0.713754647,2.750929368,7.420074349,17.23420074,27.67286245
1982-12-01,0.795539033,2.788104089,7.31598513,18.04460967,29.76951673`);

const g3 = new Dygraph(
  document.getElementById("graphdiv3"),
  'data:application/text+csv;base64,' + csv, {
    labelsDiv: document.getElementById('status'),
    labelsSeparateLines: true,
    labelsKMB: true,
    legend: 'always',
    xlabel: 'Date',
    ylabel: 'Area',
    drawGrid: false,
    rollPeriod: 10,
    showRoller: true,
    fillGraph: true,
    fillAlpha: 1.0,
    showRangeSelector: true,
    interactionModel: Dygraph.defaultInteractionModel,
    legendFormatter: reverseLegendFormatter,
    labelsSeparateLines: false // Really shines here!
  }
)

function reverseLegendFormatter(data) {
  let g = data.dygraph;
  if (g.getOption('showLabelsOnHighlight') !== true) return '';
  let sepLines = g.getOption('labelsSeparateLines'), htmlLines = [];
  if (typeof data.x === 'undefined') {
    if (g.getOption('legend') != 'always') return '';
    data.series.reverse()
      .filter(series => series.isVisible)
      .forEach(series => {
        htmlLines.push(`
          <span style="font-weight:bold; color:${series.color}">
            ${series.dashHTML} ${series.labelHTML}
          </span>
        `);
      });
  } else {
    htmlLines.push(`${data.xHTML}:`);
    data.series.reverse()
      .filter(series => series.isVisible)
      .forEach(series => {
        htmlLines.push(`
          <span${ series.isHighlighted ? ' class="highlight"' : '' }>
            <b><span style="color: ${series.color}">${series.labelHTML}</span></b>:
            &#160;${series.yHTML}
          </span>
        `);
      });
  }
  return htmlLines.join(sepLines ? '<br />' : '');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dygraph/2.1.0/dygraph.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dygraph/2.1.0/dygraph.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="graphdiv3" style="width:1000px; height:300px;"></div>
<div id="status" class="status"></div>
```